# java.util.NoSuchElementException error don't know how to fix

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file that contains a table of integers into a 13-by-17 2D array but I am getting a NoSuchElementException error that I do not know how to fix.
For more context on the homework I am doing click the link: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/assignments/mozart.html

```
96   22  141   41  105  122   11   30   70  121   26    9  112   49  109   14
32    6  128   63  146   46  134   81  117   39  126   56  174   18  116   83
69   95  158   13  153   55  110   24   66  139   15  132   73   58  145   79
40   17  113   85  161    2  159  100   90  176    7   34   67  160   52  170
148   74  163   45   80   97   36  107   25  143   64  125   76  136    1   93
104  157   27  167  154   68  118   91  138   71  150   29  101  162   23  151
152   60  171   53   99  133   21  127   16  155   57  175   43  168   89  172
119   84  114   50  140   86  169   94  120   88   48  166   51  115   72  111
98  142   42  156   75  129   62  123   65   77   19   82  137   38  149    8
3   87  165   61  135   47  147   33  102    4   31  164  144   59  173   78
54  130   10  103   28   37  106    5   35   20  108   92   12  124   44  131

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Waltz {
    private static int minuetROWS = 13;
    private static int trioROWS = 7;
    private static int COLS = 17;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Brandizzy\\Downloads\\minuet.txt"); // Creates file object to read file.
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        Waltz a = new Waltz(); // Creates an instance of the class.
        String[][] minuet = a.getMinuet(file); // Calls the method getMinuet takes txt file in "file".
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(minuet));

    }
    /* This method takes the txt file "minuet.txt" as a parameter and stores the
    file information into a 2D array called minuet.*/
    public String[][] getMinuet(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String[][] minuet = new String[minuetROWS][COLS];
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(file);
            for(int i = 0; i< minuet.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < COLS;j ++){
                    String[] line = sc1.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
                    minuet[i][j] = line[j];
                }
                sc1.close();
            }
            sc.close();
            }
        return minuet;
    }

}
```

Comment: Should post your stack trace so we an see what is firing the error.

Comment: Think about what sc1.nextLine does and whether you should be doing that for every element of the 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and good luck with your homework.  Since it is an assignment, I'll try to give you a hint instead of a full answer.

You'll note [from the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) that `Scanner#nextLine()` is the only thing in your example that can throw a `NoSuchElementException`.  You might want to see if you can figure out why your `nextLine()` invocation concludes that there is no next line to advance to.